# Should I connect or remove the paper insulation layer on wires when installing a new plug?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have 12/2 600v cable i need to splice into a plug but it has paper and a cloth like materials in the cable with the wire. Do I need to connect the cloth and paper to ground or just take them off and connect my black and white to the plug in order to create a complete cable with the plug?

Comment: I just saw this on an episode of "How its Made" the other day.  The cloth/paper layer is added so the outer jacket of the cord doesn't stick to the wires inside.  It makes the cord more flexible.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't find outdoor wire to be less flexible than indoor. Only the latter tends to have the fiber layer. I suspect it has more to do with thermal protection of the jacket.

Answer (score 3):

Cloth and paper do not conduct electricity, so there is no use connecting them to any terminal. Simply snip them back.

If you bought 12/2 cable which is **line cord** specifically made to be cordage, it won't have a ground.

If you bought 12/2 NM cable, that will have a ground, but it is NOT to be used as cordage and should not be connected to a plug.

Answer (score 2):

The cloth/paper wrappers are  part of the insulation. Normally you'd remove them when you strip the wire. They're not intended to be electrically connected as the mesh sheath on a coaxial cable might.